# Firewall Policies vs Firewall Rules

Tags: firewall

I just want to understand some concepts related to the firewall. Is there any difference between saying **firewall policies** and **firewall rules**? Can we say a firewall includes a set of policies each of which defines a set of special rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though there are (as far as I know) no strict definitions, you say that *policies* are the abstract, high level definitions of what traffic should and shouldn't be allowed. Firewall *rules* are the translation of policies into practical configuration.

For example: the policy *"allow only management traffic from trusted networks"* is translated into rules which allow traffic from `192.2.0.0/24` to `TCP/22` and from `192.2.100.0/24` to `TCP/3389`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would agree with your definitions, but, unfortunately, different vendors have different definitions since there is no standard. I have seen firewall documentation which basically equates policy with rule, and I guess that does make sense for firewalls which can only have one policy by your definition.

Comment: Yes I also agree with you. It is a vender-dependent definition. Thank you